A better DNS changer app for Android
I need a stronger (lack of better wording) non root DNS changer app for Android. On PCs many Windows and Linux apps do work just fine for the most part, not needing extra features. Sometimes just using the OSs' included resolver do not work well especially abroad with different ISPs, laws, etc.
On Android it changed dramatically, I need more extra features. I could easily use a VPN (and am subscribed) but IMHO I just want a simpler alternative. I have tried testing on 4 different providers and ISPs, and supposedly they are not the worst.
all

InviZibile
and Intra

some

Nebulo
, Rethink
, many minimal DNS changer

none (used to work 100% years ago T_T)

private and WIFI DNS settings

Intra is what I am currently using, but would prefer a no frills alternative. I dislike any kind of stats (easily disabled via root) but would prefer not to.
Seems the keyword I am looking for is anti DNS manipulation. As time goes by I guess it is going to be a cat and mouse game like always.
UPD
Also DPI (deep packet inspection), SNI (server name indication) etc.

Seems VPNs are the way to go as DPI does get better (or worse) over time. Some apps that work before are not doing well now.
all

Unicorn
a bit too minimal with only 2 servers and can not add any more

some

DPITunnel
, PowerTunnel

